# Mysql - How can I query about the past (go back in time)?

Tags: mysql, audit

I have a database that it is always changing... updates, inserts and deletes.
For statistics reason, we need sometime to "go back in time" (-: and query the database like we are in the past.

For example:
I have a table named `user`, I have updated yesterday one of the users like the following:

```
update user set status = 1 where user_id = 2656
```

The old `status` was 0, so if i can "go back in time" to yesterday and query it ill get `status` 0, and if ill query it now, ill get `status` 1.
I know that one way to do it is to trigger update,insert and delete and log it to different tables, but it is not so clean, and will make the development complicated.

I hope you got me right, not so simple to explain for none English speaker...

**Edit-1**
We have few algorithms in the application and we fix them and upgrade them always, we have to know how the database was in the past so we can work on the algorithms, we have queries/interface that can be changed to support that (I am aware that this is not a one week project, we have the resources for that)

Thanks

Comment: Show your tables , and what you have tried till now ?

Comment: Personally I think this is a rather bad idea. If you need to change a lot of data, you'll need some sort of interface. Also, if you've changed a `0` to a `1`, it's equally as easy to change `1` to `0`. I don't see why you need a "time-machine" like feature.

Comment: @JamWaffles,@DhruvPathak,@Robin Castlin -   I Edit the question (see Edit-1) thanks

Comment: There is no way to "query the past" in MySQL (or any other SQL-server as far as I know). Your only option is to implement some sort of backup or audit trails system. Once you've accepted that, there are a lot of options available to you...

Comment: @Ivar, you have obviously never heard of the binary log, or you would know that what you are saying is nonsense.

Comment: @Johan In my opinion the binary log qualifies as "some sort of backup or audit trails system". It won't allow you to simply query the past. While it might be easy to set up/enable, I don't think it's optimal for the purpose of this question.

Comment: @Ivar, In that case I would go for triggers on update, delete and insert. You can even retrieve your old updates, if you replicate your binlog to a slave full of blackhole tables wih triggers. After that you can query to your hearts content. I do believe there are some tools that can query the binlog (provided it's in row format, not SQL-statement format) using SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 Enable the binary log**.
This will safe all updates, inserts and deletes.
There are query tools for the binlog.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html
http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-read-mysql-binary-log-files-binlog-with-mysqlbinlog/

**Option 2 Create a trigger that saves the changes**
The trigger save a data into a parallell database that has the same layout as the original database, except all tables have two extra fields. A unqiue id called `log_id` and a timestamp. Whenever a field changes you have the trigger log in in the log.
You need at least an after_update and after_delete trigger and I would recommend a after_insert trigger as well. If you feel like it, you can add a third field to every tables called `operation`, which is an `ENUM('insert','delete','update')`.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER au_table1_each AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into back_to_the_past.table1_log (`timestamp`,operation,f1,f2,f3.f4) 
    values (now(), 'update', OLD.f1, OLD.f2, OLD.f3, OLD.f4);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Of course if you create an extra timestamp type field in `table1_log` you don't need to get it explicitly to `now()` the DB will do that.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: Can I actually get the binlog and convert to a database so i can query it normally? thanks

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/162110/mysql-binlog-analyzing-and-reporting-tool

Comment: Option 0: use a schema which stores multi versions (option 2 is a specific instance of how to maintain data in such a schema - but not the onlt way)

Comment: @symcbean, do you have a name and a hyperlink for this schema?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a "time machine" for an OLTP-database is often implemented using a **Data Warehouse**.

Your [OLTP (Online transaction processing) database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) need only contain the latest data, so your applications can work. Stuffing it with historical data will indeed pollute the schema, slow it down, make it more complex, etcetera.

Your [Datawarehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) will contain LOTS of data, but does not need to accept frequent writes. Instead, you use it to generate reports, analyse trends, make predictions. It is read-optimized, an [OLAP (On-Line Analytical Processing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have resources as you say, I suggest you buy yourself a SAN and put your MySQL data files on a virtual disk. Set up incremental snapshots of that disk at whatever inteval you want.

Whenever you need to look up some historical data, you could create a new virtual disk based on one of those snapshots. Mount the new disk with another MySQL server, and ... play with it.

This method will not give you a continous timeline, so if that is needed you should ignore this suggestion...